# What does cryptsetup-bin does

Tags: cryptsetup

If cryptsetup-bin is missing in cryptsetup can we be assured that our device is encrypted.please let me know

Comment: Your question seems to be rather vague. Please [edit] your question and add more background information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.